# Use ImageMagick as component without installing

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick, im4java

I am developing a java application where i require image conversion and I want to use imageMagick for that.

I made a java program using jmagick.jar in classpath and then installed imageMagick. Then the program was running as expected. But i want to pack imageMagick component in my application, so separate installation should not be done.

So i copied the program files from original place to somewhere else and uninstall imageMagick. Then Ii gave JVM argument as `-Djava.library.path="F:\\ImageMagick-6.3.9-Q16\\"`

So i am getting error as Exception in thread "main":

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: F:\ImageMagick-6.3.9-Q16\jmagick.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

So please tell me how and where to give dependent libraries path in program and how to use imageMagick without installing. I tried searching through web. but didn't get any useful information

Answer (score 1):

Rather then coping dll files around, use something like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to manage your dependencies. Your project now has a dependency of jmagick; which in turn, has a prequisite of ImageMagick (see [section 0 in JMagick INSTALL](https://github.com/techblue/jmagick/blob/master/INSTALL#L4) document.)

> How to use ImageMagick without installing

You can not. The system running your application will need to have Imagemagick libraries, headers, and delegates to satisfy JMagick.

[image: JMagick dependency]

Ideally your project should included a installation script that checks for system dependencies, and respects environment variables that may be defined by a system administrator. See [ImageMagick hints](https://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/graphics/imagemagick.hints) for details that can influence installation.